# Design pattern with decorator

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

[image]

```
public class DecoratorPatternDemo {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Shape circle = new Circle();

  Shape redCircle = new RedShapeDecorator(new Circle());

  Shape redRectangle = new RedShapeDecorator(new Rectangle());
  System.out.println("Circle with normal border");
  circle.draw();

  System.out.println("\nCircle of red border");
  redCircle.draw();

  System.out.println("\nRectangle of red border");
  redRectangle.draw();
 }
}
```

Anyone can tell me what're the benefits of creating an instance of `RedShapeDecorator` with reference type `Shape`? (I can understand the reason with `Shape circle = new Circle()` because this is polymorphism). But not with `RedShapeDecorator`. Is that the same if I do this

> RedShapeDecorator redCircle = new RedShapeDecorator(new Circle());

instead of

> Shape redCircle = new RedShapeDecorator(new Circle()); .

Thank you.

Comment: If you only need a `Shape` since you only call the `draw()` method, using `RedShapeDecorator redCircle` would be too much of implementation detail.

Comment: `i can understand the reason with Shape circle = new Circle() because this is polymorphism`. `RedShapeDecorator`  is also polymorphism.  It's upto you how much details you want to expose or say want to sign out a contaract based on interface used or just directly want to use concrete class to use some utility as well...

Comment: yeah i know it is polymorphism . but what i meant that i could understand the reason of using polymorphism with circle ..but why use polymorphism with redDecortor :) ..any reason ?

Comment: There should be or was a duck at right lower corner of your monitor, explain to it the reason for using polymorphism with circle and see if the same reasons apply to the decorator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RedShapeDecorator` is transitively a `Shape` as well, since `RedShapeDecorator` is a `ShapeDecorator`, which is, in turn, a `Shape`. The benefit of using the `redCircle` object in terms of `Shape` is that the fact that `redCircle` is actually a decorator is hidden from other portions of the code in much the same way as `Shape circle = new Circle()` hides the fact that `circle` is actually of type `Circle`, rather than `Shape` (your polymorphic example).

In general, decorators do not include methods that are not also included in the interface for the decorator (usually, an instance of `Shape` is provided to the decorator through the constructor, as is the case with `RedShapeDecorator` and therefore, once the decorator has been instantiated, there is usually no benefit to referring to it by the decorator type), and therefore, a decorator instance is often declared using the interface type rather than the type of the decorator.